# How to Apply-templates for Sibling nodes using a Substring to search matching nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am not sure why this applly-templates will not work, I have called a Template in my XSL file that searches for an element to have the answer "YES" to then continue with another template, but that's where it ends as I cannot seem to get the next template to work.
(using XSLT 1.0)

Example XML (this is an excerpt from a larger XML just to show you a point)

```
<Properties>
    ...
    <benCut_1__1_ formula="">Yes</benCut_1__1_>
    <CTRRad_1__2_ formula="">Yes</CTRRad_1__2_>
    <CBlRad_1__2_ formula="">Yes</CBlRad_1__2_>
    <CBRRad_1__2_ formula="">Yes</CBRRad_1__2_>
    <CTLRad_1__2_ formula="">Yes</CTLRad_1__2_>
    <CBlRad_1__3_ formula="">Yes</CBlRad_1__3_>
    <CBRRad_1__3_ formula="">Yes</CBRRad_1__3_>
    <CTLRad_1__3_ formula="">Yes</CTLRad_1__3_>
    <CTRRad_1__3_ formula="">Yes</CTRRad_1__3_>
    <bencut_1__2_ formula="">Yes</bencut_1__2_>
    <benCut_2__1_ formula="">Yes</benCut_2__1_>
    <benCutH_2__1_ formula="">21mm</benCutH_2__1_>
    <benCutW_2__1_ formula="">21mm</benCutW_2__1_>
    <benCutx_2__1_ formula="">21mm</benCutx_2__1_>
    <benCutY_2__1_ formula="">21mm</benCutY_2__1_>
    <benCTR_2__1_ formula="">21mm</benCTR_2__1_>
    <benCTl_2__1_ formula="">21mm</benCTl_2__1_>
    ...
</Properties>
```

Firstly I apply-templates to search for any of the "benCut_" or "bencut_" results as the data comes out with different cases (that issue is seperate from this problem).

```
<xsl:template match="Properties" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(translate(name(),'BENCUT','bencut'),'bencut_')]" />
</xsl:template>
```

Then I need to run the next apply-templates to any of the "bencut_" that has the value "Yes", and find the the end of the string (the last 6 characters create a matching string to find other values in the XML that I need to extract as a group and present differently

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(translate(name(),'BENCUT','bencut'),'bencut_')]" >
    <xsl:if test="text()='Yes'">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[contains(name(),substring(name(),string-length(name())-5))]" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This is where it starts to fail, because I need to check the siblings of the "bencut_" node that contain the same tail string and they could be preceding or following
(I removed my original select of 'following-sibling::*[contains(name(),substring(name(),string-length(name())-5))] | preceding-sibling::*[contains(name(),substring(name(),string-length(name())-5)]' to try and debug code)

[Also really unsure why "|" worked in another situation when "and" would not if anyone has an explanation about that]

This was my final template that I was going to run which was going to format what each of the other siblings I found looked and presented like.

```
<xsl:template match="following-sibling::*[contains(name(),substring(name(),string-length(name())-5))]" >
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
</xsl:template>
```

the end result was to find all the matching tails "_1__2_" for example and be able to see the following data considering things like CTRRad_1__2_ is Cutout Top Right Radius.

Cutout (1) section (2);
Top Right Radius - Yes
Bottom Left Radius - Yes
Cutout Height - 21mm
Cutout Width - 21mm
...

There would be 1-11 cutouts of 1-3 sections, ie 33 possible cutout blocks.

Comment: You forgot to provide the wanted result from the transformation. Please, provide.

Comment: @Dimitre - the example was provided, I want to read all the *_1__2_ elements, each of them start with different pieces so there will be "CTRRad_1__2_" and "CTLRad_1__2_" when I see the CTRRad* I want to then run another <xsl:if> to change that to read "Cutout Top Right Radius",  it's recognizing the partial strings of a template that has me stumped, the rest i can do myself, so you can output anything you like if you can loop all the matching "_1__2_" and all the "_1__3_" etc and then still be able to see the start of the name() to work out the next part.

Comment: @Alastair, you make it the most easy to help if you provide everything inside the question, edit it if necessary. If you literally provide the snippet that you expect as result it would be more helpful than a prose explanation (though that may add even more relevant information)

Comment: I might have resolved my own issue, Just trying to work out why I cannot use the following: '<xsl:apply-templates select="contains(name(),substring(name(),string-length(name())-5))">' at the moment I would have to hard code it to see if it contains '_1__2_' which is not what i want.

Comment: Using `match="following-sibling::x[...]"` should give you a syntax error. It's not a valid match pattern in any version of XSLT. I'm not sure what you think it would mean if it were allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to understand what exactly your problem is. First you say:

> it starts to fail, because I need to check the siblings of the
>   "bencut_" node that contain the same tail string and they could be
>   preceding or following

then you say:

> it's recognizing the partial strings of a template that has me
>   stumped,

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Properties">
    <root>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(translate(name(), 'BENCUT', 'bencut'), 'bencut_')][.='Yes']" />
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(translate(name(), 'BENCUT', 'bencut'), 'bencut_')]">
    <xsl:variable name="key" select="substring(name(), string-length(name()) - 5)" />
    <group key="{$key}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[contains(name(), $key)]" mode="group"/>
    </group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="group">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <group key="_1__1_">
      <benCut_1__1_ formula="">Yes</benCut_1__1_>
   </group>
   <group key="_1__2_">
      <CTRRad_1__2_ formula="">Yes</CTRRad_1__2_>
      <CBlRad_1__2_ formula="">Yes</CBlRad_1__2_>
      <CBRRad_1__2_ formula="">Yes</CBRRad_1__2_>
      <CTLRad_1__2_ formula="">Yes</CTLRad_1__2_>
      <bencut_1__2_ formula="">Yes</bencut_1__2_>
   </group>
   <group key="_2__1_">
      <benCut_2__1_ formula="">Yes</benCut_2__1_>
      <benCutH_2__1_ formula="">21mm</benCutH_2__1_>
      <benCutW_2__1_ formula="">21mm</benCutW_2__1_>
      <benCutx_2__1_ formula="">21mm</benCutx_2__1_>
      <benCutY_2__1_ formula="">21mm</benCutY_2__1_>
      <benCTR_2__1_ formula="">21mm</benCTR_2__1_>
      <benCTl_2__1_ formula="">21mm</benCTl_2__1_>
   </group>
</root>
```

---

P.S.

A more efficient version would use a **key**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="elem-by-tail" match="*" use="substring(name(), string-length(name()) - 5)" />

<xsl:template match="/Properties">
    <root>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(translate(name(), 'BENCUT', 'bencut'), 'bencut_')][.='Yes']" />
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(translate(name(), 'BENCUT', 'bencut'), 'bencut_')]">
    <xsl:variable name="key" select="substring(name(), string-length(name()) - 5)" />
    <group key="{$key}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elem-by-tail', $key)" mode="group"/>
    </group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="group">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I like what you did there with that one @Michael and can see that achieves what I was chasing in my question, in my live version I have approached slightly differently, but I used what I saw in your example to change how I was actually doing it, thanks.